# Flip true values that are preceded by another true value in a cumulative fashion

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array containing `bool` values and I want to flip those `True` that are preceded by another `True` in a cumulative fashion (i.e. flips of previous elements affect subsequent elements). For example:

```
array    = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]).astype(bool)
expected = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]).astype(bool)
```

The third element is not flipped since when stepping cumulatively through the array the second element first flips to `False` and hence the third is not preceded by a `True` anymore.

This can be realized with the following loop:

```
solution = [False]
for x in array:
    solution.append(x and not solution[-1])
solution = np.array(solution[1:])
```

This basically resembles a non-commutative operator which maps the following values and gets applied in a cumulative fashion:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|  op1  |  op2  |  out  |
+-------+-------+-------+
| False | False | False |
| False | True  | True  |
| True  | False | False |
| True  | True  | False |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

For that reason I can't use any of the `np.logical_*.accumulate` functions. If however there was a way to chain multiple ufuncs (namely `np.logical_not` and `np.logical_and`, no matter in what order) then this would work; a similar solution can be realized using `itertools.accumulate` with a `lambda` that chains the operators:

```
# applying `not` to the left operand:
s1 =  np.fromiter(it.accumulate([False] + array.tolist(),
                  lambda x, y: (not x) and y))[1:]

# applying `not` to the output:
s2 = ~np.fromiter(it.accumulate([True] + array.tolist(),
                  lambda x, y: not (x and y)))[1:]
```

However I am not aware of a way to chain ufuncs in such a way in Numpy.

Maybe there is another way to accomplish that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting your operator table it looks to me like "<" fits the bill:

```
res = np.less.accumulate(array)
(res==expected).all()
# True
```